# draw dotted/dashed rectangles in Eagle schematic

Tags: eaglecad

I'm trying to draw some dashed/dotted rectangles in Eagle schematic to annotate functional groups like in [this link](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/Arduino/Ardumoto_v13.pdf)

I tried to draw rectangle and switch it to different types e.g. symbol, net, info... all failed so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbol, net, info, etc. are different *layers* within the editor. Changing the layer of a line may or may not change its color, but has no other effect on its style or width.

You need to use the "change style" command. You can select Continuous, LongDash, ShortDash or DashDot.

Also, when you're laying down wires, there's a "Style" dropdown available on the toolbar.

Comment: I'd say put your dashed rectangle in the "tPlace" layer (use bPlace if you want the rectangular outline on the bottom side). This can then be used for identifying/highlighting different sections in your PCB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the wire in a different color, you need to put it in a different layer. Before drawing the wire, click the "Change object properties" wrench, then "Layer..." and select a layer, e.g. Info. Wires you draw will then be gray. Right-click the wire, select Properties, and then you can change it to "shortdash", for instance. The result will be a gray dashed line like your link shows. You'll probably want to change the wire layer back to Nets when you're done.